# How to prevent displaying Push Notifications when app is open in Android using react-native-push-notifications?

Tags: android, react-native, push-notification

I would like to completely disable the display of push notifications when the app is open. I know it is possible to manage the AppState (background / active) in React Native. But I don't know how to disable the appearance of notifications: I would like to use the localNotifications, but using them I see two the same: one launched by the plugin automatically and one displayed by me through the localNotification. How can I do?

Using [react-native-push-notifications](https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification).